# Smooth page transition like Youtube

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube

I'm very interesting with Youtube page transition. When you open a video, then move to another video that have different URL. The browser page not refreshed like usually when open a conventional web pages. It's just like you are not move to another page, you are in the same page whereas not.

Is there any javascript/jquery plugin to do this?

Comment: here is a good article about that...

http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/10/30/medium-style-page-transition/

Answer (score 0):

If you're wondering how to load content and not reload/refresh a webpage, then you'll be referring to Ajax (Asynchronous JavaScript and XML).

These should help you out:

1. [Ajax W3C](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/)
2. [jQuery Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: No, I think it's not Ajax method. In Ajax, the URL in browser address bar will not change, but in Youtube site, the URL was changed. It's not Ajax, it's a page transition manipulation.

Comment: There are a few other examples that address this issue such as:
http://tinyurl.com/m656sz5